# How to turn Python wheel or egg into executable on Linux

Tags: python, linux, executable

I have a python program that, using `setuptools`, I can build producing an egg or wheel file.

I'm trying to understand the correct way to make this program easily distributable. I would like to be able to give a single file to another linux machine (probably Ubuntu) and run a few commands, and then execute the program directly.

Currently I can install the program, which allows it to be run as follows:

```
$ python3 -m myprogram
```

This would be fine if my goal was to be able to import it into other Python programs, but I'd rather have it runnable from anywhere ... like `grep` or other utilities.

I understand that it is more typical to add a shebang to a script, but I'm trying to make something that can be easily shared, even when there are multiple files and dependencies, and even when the recipient doesn't have typical Python tools like `pip` available.

Comment: You can [include `console_scripts` in your package's `entry_points`](http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/command-line-scripts.html) (declared in `setup.py`). This will still require `setuptools` to be present and the package to be installed, but will allow you to call the package without needing `python3 -m ...`.

Comment: You may want to try [Python Zip Application Archive Format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipapp.html#the-python-zip-application-archive-format).

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Thanks much, that did it.

Comment: See [Set PYTHONPATH according to requirements.txt at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38642658/95735) and don't be mislead by the title which is unfortunate.

Comment: Sadly, the tutorial referenced by @ThomasOrozco gives a 404 now. Using the wayback machine, it is available at https://web.archive.org/web/20160402114428/http://python-packaging.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html

Comment: @hlongmore If someone were to extract a useful answer from that tutorial, I'd upvote and accept. Would probably be more robust for the one that finds his way here in 2025.