# Python: Set PYTHONPATH according to requirements.txt at runtime

Tags: python

I have a Python application that comes with a command line script. I expose the script via `setuptools` "entry point" feature. Whenever a user runs the script, I would like the environment to be consistent with the package's `requirements.txt`. This means that the environment must contain versions of each dependency package that match the version specifiers in `requirements.txt`.

I know that this can be achieved with `venv`/`virtualenv` by making my users create a virtual environment, install `requirements.txt` in it, and activate that virtual environment whenever they run the script. I do not want to impose this burden of manually invoking `virtualenv` on users. Ruby's `bundler` solves this problem by providing `bundler/setup`-- when loaded, it modifies Ruby's `$LOAD_PATH` to reflect the contents of the `Gemfile` (analogue of `requirements.txt`). Thus it can be placed at the top of a script to transparently control the runtime environment. Does Python have an equivalent? That is, a way to set the environment at runtime according to `requirements.txt` without imposing additional complexity on the user?

Comment: On windows: since you're running a command line script, why not reading the file and use `setx PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre OK, I will look into that, but I am hoping for a cross-platform solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build Python project including dependencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606773/how-to-build-python-project-including-dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Python have an equivalent? That is, a way to set the environment at runtime according to requirements.txt without imposing additional complexity on the user?

Yes, more than one.

One is [pex](https://pex.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

> pex is a library for generating .pex (Python EXecutable) files which
>   are executable Python environments in the spirit of virtualenvs.

and the other is [Platter](http://platter.pocoo.org/dev/):

> Platter is a tool for Python that simplifies deployments on Unix
>   servers. It’s a thin wrapper around pip, virtualenv and wheel and aids
>   in creating packages that can install without compiling or downloading
>   on servers.

Comment: Thanks so much. `pex` is a perfect solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it wouldn't be possible for a Python program to install its own dependencies before importing them, but it is unheard of in the Python community.

I'd rather look at options to make your application a standalone executable, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112698/py2exe-generate-single-executable-file), for instance.

Comment: Thanks Markus. Let me clarify: I do not need the script to *install* the dependencies when run. I am OK with having my users do a one-time `pip install --requirements.txt` after they have downloaded the package. The issue is future stability. The app uses specific versions of specific packages. I need to make sure that, after installation, the executable will indefinitely run in an environment with those specific versions, even if a user updates those packages. The solution should also be cross-platform (Windows, Mac, Linux). I will look into `py2exe` but I'm hoping for a simpler solution.

Comment: [certbot](https://github.com/certbot/certbot) (née Letsencrypt) installs its own dependencies in a virtualenv when run, though technically you're running a shell script that does the installation and then calls the actual program.